# JPasswordField naming convention

Tags: java

A short question, what is the naming convention for a password field? Like the when you put it like this;

```
JPasswordField variableName = new JPasswordField(20);
```

For exampled a JTextField is txt, JLabel is lbl and JComboBox is cbo etc.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about a naming convention for the variable?  If so, the answer is always "whatever makes your code readable".

Comment: Yes like textfield is txt, label is lbl and combobox is cbo (Should have explained it better in the main question)

Comment: And who said txt is a convention for textfield and cbo for combobox?! According to Robert C. Martin (author of clean code) never ever use a name for an identifier which can not be pronounced!

Answer (score 0):

Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.

Variable names should be short yet meaningful. The choice of a variable name should be mnemonic- that is, designed to indicate to the casual observer the intent of its use.

One-character variable names should be avoided except for temporary "throwaway" variables. Common names for temporary variables are i, j, k, m, and n for integers; c, d, and e for characters.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367